# AngularJS TypeError only In Chrome

Tags: jquery, angularjs

The following code fails in Chrome, but works in Firefox and IE. When the code reaches ".find" it returns "TypeError: undefined is not a function".

```
angular.forEach(data, function(data) {

            pointInfoFactory.getPointDetail(data).then(function(data) {
                var pointDetail = data.data;
                var pointToUpdate = $scope.pointDetail.find(function(existingPoint){
                    return existingPoint.PointID == pointDetail.PointID;
                });
                    if(pointToUpdate){
                        angular.extend(pointToUpdate,pointDetail);
                        console.log(pointToUpdate.PointID +" "+pointDetail.PointID+" point match found!");
                    }
                    else{
                        $scope.pointDetail.push(pointDetail);
                    }
```

Comment: What does console.log($scope.pointDetail) give you in Chrome?

Comment: Need more context. Also, are you sure it's actually working in those other browsers? Or are they just not reporting the error?

Comment: console.log($scope.pointDetail) is providing my array of objects  [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
0: Object
1: Object
2: Object
3: Object
4: Object
5: Object
6: Object
7: Object
8: Object
9: Object
length: 10
__proto__: Array[0]

Comment: `angular.forEach(data, function(data) {` can you avoid using same name for collection and single element `angular.forEach(dataList, function(data) {`

Comment: I am pretty sure that it is working in the other broswers because my $scope is updating and changing values

Comment: HarishR - updated data to dataList and still producing the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) is a proposed feature in ECMAScript 6 and is only available in FireFox 31+ and in Chrome 30+ (with experimental flag turned on). ([See full compat here](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/)) I'm not sure why it's working for you in IE because it's not supposed to be supported (I just tested in IE 11).

To ensure compatibility, you might want to use a less elegant approach with `for` or `angular.forEach`.

Comment: Wow, turned on experimental javascript and everything started working. Thanks for curing my headache!

Comment: No worries. How did you get it working in IE? Can you confirm it's working and share how you got it to work?

Comment: Ok, after alot of tracing IE is doing something really strange, its clearing my array and pushing all the data into it. (this happens in a previous function but not on a timeout or interval) I am throwing no errors though which I also find strange. Will have to do more digging